# Pretty links with add_rewrite_rule and add_query_var

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to pass a variable from the url into a wordpress post.

1) I added add_query_var into functions.php, to retrieve the query string from the url

```
add_filter( 'init', 'add_model_more_query_var' );
function add_model_more_query_var()
{
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'model_more' );
}
```

2) I can retrieved the variable in my post with:

```
get_query_var( 'model_more', 1 );
```

The url structure that I am using is:

domain.com/post-type/post-title/?model_more=5

https://www.domain.com/model/benz/?model_more=5

https://www.domain.com/model/audi/?model_more=4

https://www.domain.com/model/ford/?model_more=12

Now I am trying to make the urls pretty, and rewrite them from

https://www.domain.com/model/benz/?model_more=5

To

https://www.domain.com/model/benz/model_more/5/

This is where I am stuck.

I have the following rewrite rule, but I get a 404 when I try to access the pretty url:

```
add_action('init','add_model_more_rewrite_rule');
function add_model_more_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^model_more/(\d*)$',
        'index.php?model_more=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: One issue I see is that you're using `^model_more` in your RegEx, where `^` specifies the beginning of the string (in the case of `add_rewrite_rule` this means the requested URL path). So, if your path is "/model/benze/model_more/5/", the `^model_more` will never match since the beggingin of the math is `/model/`.

Comment: Is `model/benz` a custom post type?

Comment: model = custom post type and 
benz = post title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your regular expression:

```
^model_more/(\d*)$
^--- Says "match start of line"
```

In your URLs, the start of the line is actually `/model/`, so `^model_more` will never match. Instead, try a regex like this:

```
^model/[^/]+/model_more/(\d+)/?$
```

- `[^/]+` says "match anything except `/`, since I would guess there are multiple models under `/model/`.
- `(\d+)` ensures that only digits are captured - `(\d*)` would capture anything after the number.
- `/?$` says "the end of the line might be preceded by a slash, but not necessarily.

**Edit:** You can see the regex in action at https://regex101.com/r/OhOFTD/1

Comment: I dont get the 404 anymore :), but wordpress is directing the url to template archive.php, and not to single.php.  

https://www.domain.com/model/benz/?model_more=5 -> single-model.php and

https://www.domain.com/model/benz/model_more/5/ -> archive.php

Comment: If you go to `/index.php?model_more=5` do you get the page you're expecting?

Comment: no, i have to go to: /?model=benz&model_more=5

 
"model" is the custom post type, "Benz" is the post slug, and "model_more" the query var.

Comment: Gotcha, so try this: `^model/([^/]+)/model_more/(\d+)/?$` and then for the second parameter: `index.php?model=$matches[1]&model_more=$matches[2]`